# ajax call keeps failing despite success on server site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert2

I'm having some trouble with an ajax call.
When it's a success in one part, it's failing in the return.

Basically I have a PHP function to delete one ID in database.
The ajax call call the function and the PHP code deletes that row in table, but ajax call keeps faling. If I try to delete it again (the ID doesn't exist anymore), the ajax call shows as success with proper json to work.

```
function DeleteRole(e, id, role) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "Do you want to delete Role " + role + "?",
        icon: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger ml-1",
        preConfirm: function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'caller.php',
                    data: {
                        dados: JSON.stringify(id),
                        caller: 'DeleteRole',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                })
                .done(function (response) {
                    console.log("done");
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .fail(function (response) {
                    console.log("fail");
                    console.log(response);
                })
        },
        allowOutsideClick: function () {
            !Swal.isLoading()
        }
    })
};
```

PHP Function:

```
function DeleteRole($mysqli){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $response = array();
    $response["status"] = "error";
    $response["message"] = "";
    if(isset($_POST['dados'])){
        $args["id"] = validate($mysqli, $_POST["dados"]);
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM roles WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")){
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $args["id"]);
            $stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            ($stmt_result = $stmt->get_result()) or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            if ($stmt_result->num_rows>0) { 
                $row_data = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc();
                $role_name = $row_data['role_name'];
                if(crud_delete($mysqli, 'roles', $args) == true){
                    $response["status"] = "success";
                    $response["message"] = "Role ".$role_name." deleted with success";
                    echo json_encode($response);  
                }else{
                    $response["status"] = "error";
                    $response["message"] = "There was a problem deleting role ".$role_name;
                    echo json_encode($response);                               
                }
            }else{
                $response["message"] = "ID does not exists.";
                echo json_encode($response);                
            }
        }else{
            $response["message"] = "Something wrong happened.";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }else{
        $response["message"] = "No data given to work.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

So, when I first call the function for first time do delete a specific ID, it deletes from database and should ouptut:

```
                $response["status"] = "success";
                $response["message"] = "Role ".$role_name." deleted with success";
                echo json_encode($response);
```

Instead of that, it goes to fail part of my ajax call. Any clues?

EDIT:
First time to delete, I have an answer this way and appears in .fail of ajax call:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
)
{"status":"success","message":"Role Administrator deleted with success"}
```

If I do it a second time (the ID was already deleted first time) I have the following response (and goes to .done of ajax request):

```
{"status":"error","message":"ID does not exists."}
```

Comment: What does the response say in the `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: You need to use your browser's Developer Tools  to get more information. Open the Developer Tools and go to the Network area, and then run your delete operation on your page. You'll see the request to caller.php appear. Click on that request, and go to the Response tab which appears. What exactly do you see there? Also, what does it say in the Console at this time? There's likely to be a clue in the error message.

Comment: @Lapskaus, added response of both calls.

Comment: @ADyson, added response of both calls.

Comment: Ok well `Array
(
    [0] => id
)` is clearly not valid JSON, is it? That looks like the result of a `var_dump` or `print_r` debug output left lying around in your code somewhere. Therefore jQuery will unable to parse the response coming from the server into an object, because half the response is not JSON, so it can't work out what to do with it

Comment: I'm so dumb! You're right. I was from yesterday trying to solve this and forgot I added a print_r in my crud_delete function for debug purposes. Now it's removed, it's everything OK. Thanks!